# Getting error root element missing while creating schema from internal dtd above. what is the solution?

Tags: xml, dtd, internal

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE Paris [
    <!ELEMENT Paris (Hotel+)>
     <!ELEMENT Hotel (ID, Name, Stars , Facilities+, Address, Distance?, 
   Available)>
  <!ELEMENT ID (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT Name (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT Stars (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT Facilities (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT Address (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT Distance (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT Available (#PCDATA)>]>
```

I'm getting an error

> root element missing

while creating schema from internal dtd above.

What is the solution?

Comment: Your xml file doesn't have a root element, what isn't clear? Add a `Paris` element after the DTD.

Comment: Adding  a Paris element after the DTD works